# Calculating connections for fiber bundles,

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

I think I understand the concept of covariant derivative, connection, even what a fiber bundle is, but I have a very specific question: how do you calculate the connection for an specific group?

I mean, in the case of the Levi-Civita (Christoffel symbols) it's easy to see that (I'm following Frankel's *The Geometry of Physics*):

$$\boldsymbol{x}_{\alpha\beta} = \partial_{\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{x}_{\gamma}\Gamma^{\gamma}_{\beta\alpha} \, + \langle{\boldsymbol{x}_{\alpha\beta}}, \boldsymbol{N}\rangle\boldsymbol{N} $$

where the last term is the normal projection and the first term ($\boldsymbol{x}_{\gamma}\Gamma^{\gamma}_{\beta\alpha}$) is the tangential part. Noting that:

$$\langle\boldsymbol{x}_{\alpha\beta}, \boldsymbol{x}_{\mu}\rangle = \langle\boldsymbol{x}_\gamma, \boldsymbol{x}_{\mu}\rangle\Gamma^\gamma_{\beta\alpha} = g_{\gamma\mu}\Gamma^{\gamma}_{\beta\alpha} = \Gamma_{\beta\alpha,\,\mu}$$

and

$$\partial_{\beta}g_{\alpha\mu} = \langle\boldsymbol{x}_{\alpha\beta},\boldsymbol{x}_{\mu}\rangle + \langle\boldsymbol{x}_{\alpha},\boldsymbol{x}_{\mu\beta}\rangle = \Gamma_{\beta\alpha,\,\mu} + \Gamma_{\beta\mu,\,\alpha}$$

combining these expressions you get the usual formula for the Christoffel symbols you can see in many books.

My question is, ok, I understand this for the case of the connection in the spacetime, but about other connections, how can you deduce them? How do you calculate the connection ($\omega^{i}_{jk}$) for the electromagnetism or for more complex cases such as the $SU(3)$ group that mediates the strong force?

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection is special, because it is determined by the metric completely.

Other connections that appear in physics are dynamical fields, and they will be given by solving field equations. For example, the connection for electromagnetism is the vector potential $A_\mu$ and you obtain it when you solve Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Thanks, but then you have too many unknowns in your Maxwell equations. I mean, you have the electric and magnetic fields and also the connection.

Comment: 1. I don't see where the relation to physics is here, except that physics uses connections. 2. What do you mean by "deducing" or "calculating" a connection? In general, the connection is data on a bundle that is *given*. In physics, it may sometimes be calculated from equations of motion if the connection is a dynamical variable (such as Maxwell's equations written solely in terms of the four-potential), but it's not clear to me what your question actually is.

Comment: Ok. I now see you can write Maxwell equations in terms of the four-potential. But Maxwell is an easy case because the group is $U(1)$. But the strong force requires a non-abelian group, $SU(3)$, much more complicated. Do you know the procedure to find connections for more complex groups?